# Cannot access website with http:// protocol at the beginning

Tags: iis, redirect

The situation is following.

My client have a domain example.com. I can access to the site with the following urls :

1. example.com
2. www.example.com
3. http://www.example.com

But I cannot access the site with http://example.com.

Do anyone know why this happens?

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html The bindings won't lie. www.example.com and example.com are different (though you might believe they are the same).

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. From the fact that example.com works, it looks like the domain example.com pointing to right server. What I do not understand is why isn't http://example.com do not work. Isn't it suppose to be same as example.com??